# A basic calculus question.

Tags: calculus

$\Big\{ \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x-a) = L\Big\} \Longleftrightarrow \Big\{ \lim\limits_{h \to 0} f(h) = L\Big\}$

True or false?

---

**Edit:** Many thanks to the people who provided answers for this question.

I was confused about the domain of $f(x-a)$. If $D$ is the domain of $f(x)$, then the domain of $f(x-a)$ is taken to be $a + D$. For some reason I had it in my head that in some situations the domain of $f(x-a)$ might be taken to be some proper subset of $a + D$, for example $(a + D) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. I thought that then maybe the existence of $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x-a)$ might have been calculated on $(a + D) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, say, instead of $a + D$.

I should have asked *that* question (the default domain of $f(x - a)$) instead of *this* question...

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: No, it’s true outright; I’ll write up a quick answer.

Comment: True or false? Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x-a)$ for each $x$ such that $x-a$ is in the domain of $f$. Note that this implies that $x$ is in the domain of $f$ if and only if $x+a$ is in the domain of $g$, and $f(x)=g(x+a)$.

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(h)=L$. This means that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(h)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|h|<\delta_\epsilon$ and $x$ is in the domain of $f$. Let $x=h+a$, and suppose that $0<|x-a|<\delta_\epsilon$ and $x$ is in the domain of $g$. Then $h=x-a$ is in the domain of $f$, and $0<|h|<\delta_\epsilon$, so $|g(x)-L|=|f(x-a)-L|=|f(h)-L|<\epsilon$, and it follows that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x-a)=L$.

The argument that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x-a)=L$ implies that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(h)=L$ is very similar; you might want to see whether you can work it out on your own.

Comment: @bryanj: Suppose that $x$ is in the domain of $f$. Then $g(x+a)=f((x+a)-a)=f(x)$ is defined, so $x+a$ is in the domain of $g$. Conversely, suppose that $x+a$ is in the domain of $g$. Then $f(x)=f((x+a)-a)=g(x+a)$ is defined, so $x$ is in the domain of $f$. This also demonstrates the second conclusion.

Comment: @bryanj: I have no idea what you mean by *admissible*. Let $x$ be any real number in the domain of $f$. Then $x+a$ is a real number, and it is in the domain of $g$ **by the definition of** $g$.

Comment: @bryanj: We’re talking about **two** subsets of $\Bbb R$, which may well not be the same. One is the domain of $f$; the other is the domain of $g$. The domain of $g$ might even be **disjoint from** the domain of $f$.

Comment: What if: $f(x)=1$, when $x$ is irrational, and $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is rational? Let the universe D be the set of all rationals which are close to $0$, as well as as all the reals near $a$.

Comment: @bryanj: You’re just confusing yourself with this talk of a ‘universe’. What you’re calling the universe is really the domain of $f$. If you call that $D$, then the domain of $g$ is the set $D+a$, which is defined as $\{x+a:x\in D\}$.

Comment: Thank you...that makes more sense now...I'll try to ignore the fact that the existence of limits depends on the ambient space in which they're defined. ;) Thanks for your time.

Comment: @bryanj: You’re welcome. (But don’t ignore that important fact; just realize that you may sometimes be dealing with more than one domain! In practice, though, in most standard calculus problems you don’t have to worry about anything worse than domains that include endpoints of closed intervals.)

Comment: @bryanj: Now *that* I did not expect; sorry if I seemed to be talking down. And again, you’re very welcome.

Comment: No - Thank *you* very much!

Comment: @bryanj: :-) $\;$

Answer (score 3):

Let $h=x-a$. Then as $x\rightarrow a$, $h\rightarrow 0$.
This means that
\begin{align*}
L & = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}f\left(x-a\right)\\
 & = \lim_{h\rightarrow0}f\left(h\right).
\end{align*}